# Does RabbitMQ check message integrity when delivered on consumer side?

Tags: rabbitmq, checksum, data-integrity

I just went over the documentation but didn't find any mechanism on checking message integrity. Message consumption acknowledgment only checks delivered or not but what if the message payload is contaminated. Or is it supported by AMQP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ does not modify the message contents, nor does it perform integrity checks. It would be up to the publishing and consuming applications to do this. I suggest computing a checksum and adding it as a message header.